# Pyglet OpenGL Setting Fog Color

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, ctypes, pyglet

I'd like to know how to set fog color using pyglet.gl.

I couldn't find information about fog color in the [documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/), but I found [this](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFog.xml) useful. However, the code I wrote

```
pyglet.gl.glFogfv(gl.GL_FOG_COLOR, (0.5, 0.7, 1.0, 1.0))
```

produces the error: `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_float instance instead of tuple`

I'm not sure how to give it a LP_c_float from my color tuple, as it is not found in pyglet.gl or in the above documentation.

Comment: `pyglet.gl.glFogfv(gl.GL_FOG_COLOR, (GLfloat * 4)(0.5, 0.7, 1.0, 1.0))`

Comment: thanks man, it works! Why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd paramter of `pyglet.gl.glFogfv` is an array of 4 floats, sp you have to create an ctypes array by `(GLfloat * 4)`, see [pyglet.gl.glFogfv](https://programtalk.com/python-examples-amp/pyglet.gl.glFogfv/):

```
pyglet.gl.glFogfv(gl.GL_FOG_COLOR, (GLfloat * 4)(0.5, 0.7, 1.0, 1.0))
```

See [ctypes — A foreign function library for Python - Arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

> Arrays are sequences, containing a fixed number of instances of the same type.
>
> The recommended way to create array types is by multiplying a data type with a positive integer:
>
> ```
> TenPointsArrayType = POINT * 10
> ```